# Spring MVC Controller Service taking too long to respond

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat6

I am working on a spring MVC application. Where I am calling my application controller methods via Ajax call.

Its taking too long to respond. (Currently I am working on my local environment)

[image]

I am doing simple operations like change some value in the model and returning back the view.
(No database involved) in those.

Also I am using apache tiles to configure my views.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have your code on GitHub so I can check it out?

Comment: please provide some additional information (i.e. sourcecode)